# How to add dropDownList null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I am doing a report in Report Builder 3.0.
There parameter `dept` I have it as a dropdownlist.
How to make that the default was empty, to select all department.

Comment: With SQL questions you should always tag your DBMS (MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, or whichever). They differ in their features and SQL dialects. You should also usualy show table definitions and the query you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a record to an SQL result set, you would use UNION ALL, e.g.:

```
select deptno, deptname from dept
union all
select null, 'all';
```

EDIT: So now you have an entry 'all' in your dropdownlistbox with the deptno null. The query to get the data according to a selected deptno or null would be such:

```
select somedata
from sometable
where deptno = :chosendeptno or :chosendeptno is null;
```

Comment: It doesn't  decide my question, it is necessary that the default was null

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. So just guessing: I showed you how to put a null record for 'all' in a list for a dropdownlist ("How to add dropDownList null"). Maybe you want to know how to select the data for a chosen deptno then? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: There DropDownList in Report Builder, through a SQL query to the variables it selects the appropriate values from the database.
how to add a list of values constant blank record, which would be chosen by default?

Comment: Sorry, again I don't understand. Maybe this is because I don't know Report Builder. I have shown you how to select departments plus a "null department" representing "all departments". I have shown you how to select data from some table for the department chosen, i.e. for a specific department or for all departments. This would work in about any programming environment, be it Java, C#, PHP, whatever. But well, maybe Report Builder has another concept I don't know of. I've tagged your request with "reportbuilder", so hopefully someone who knows that program can help.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your answer was helpful for me. I made through Union ALL Select ' ' as deptname